# Finding average of last row java 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays

Hey new to arrays in java and just wondering how I can find specific values in a 2d array. I need to find the last row of randomly generated numbers in an array but I really only know how to find the grand total.

Current code:

```
public class Arraypractice {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert rows here:");
    int rows = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Insert columns here: ");
    int columns = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Personal info");
    System.out.println();

    int[][] arr = new int[rows][columns];
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int r = rand.nextInt(10000-100)+100;
            arr[i][j] = r;
        }
    }
    int max = arr[0][0];
    int min = arr[0][0];
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++) {
            int value = arr[i][j];
            if(value > max)
                max = value;
            if(value < min)
                min = value;
            total += value;
            if(value == 10000)
                break;
            else if(value <= 9999 && value > 999) 
                System.out.print(" ");
            else
                System.out.print("  ");
            System.out.print(value);
            System.out.print("\t");

    }
        System.out.println();

}
    System.out.print("Maximum: "+max+ "\t");
    System.out.print("Minimum: "+min+ "\t");
    System.out.print("Average: "+total/ (rows*columns));
}
```

}

Comment: Don't create the `Random` inside the loop. Move the `new Random` call up before the nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to compute the average of an array:

```java
public static double average(int[] values) {
    if (values.length == 0) return 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int v : values) {
        sum += v;
    }
    return sum / values.length;
}
```

Then, pass the last row into the function.

```
double lastAverage = average(arr[arr.length-1]);
```